# Use a different command variation on Solaris

Tags: bash, unix

Since Solaris `grep` by default doesn't have the `-E` option, I would have to update my `bash` to work with a specific `grep`. This is what I do.

It works on the command line, but when I put it in the bash file, it looks like the script doesn't pick it up and still uses the normal `grep`. (I do not want to change the whole $PATH.)

Please advise:

```
export isSolaris=`uname -a | grep -i "sunos"`
if  [ -n "$isSolaris" ]; then
        alias grep="/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E";
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` and `ksh` don't process aliases defined in a file until after the file is read... which means you can't define it in the same script that will use it.  You *can* put it in another file and `.` (`source`) that into your script, though.

Alternately, use a shell function.

```
mygrep() {
  if test -n "$isSolaris"; then
    /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E ${1+"$@"}
  else
    grep ${1+"$@"}
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `egrep` instead; it probably works everywhere, even though POSIX/SUS doesn't list it as a command any more.  (SUS v2 from 1997 listed `egrep` as a 'legacy' utility; POSIX 1003.1:2004 omitted `egrep`).